# Comparar valores de arreglos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola soy novato en programación JavaScript mi situación es la siguiente: tengo dos arreglos de los cuales necesito recorrer los valores del arreglo "A" y determinar si existen en el arreglo "B". Esto se debería hacer dentro de un condicional If para ejecutar diferentes instrucciones según sea verdadero o falso, cuales son los mejores métodos pare esta practica?

```
var ArregloA = new Array("rojo", "azul", "verde");
var ArregloB = new Array("rojo", "amarillo", "verde", "morado", "azul", "violeta");
```

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Qué has intentado? Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podes hacer es:

```
const arrA = ['rojo', 'azul', 'verde']
const arrB = ['rojo', 'amarillo', 'verde', 'morado', 'azul', 'violeta']

arrA.every(elem => arrB.includes(elem)) // true si todos los elementos de arrA estan en arrB

arrB.every(elem => arrA.includes(elem)) // true si todos los elementos de arrB estan en arrA
```

El método **every** lo que hace es determinar si todos los elementos en el array satisfacen una condición. (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/every).

En este caso la condición es si cada uno de los elementos del array se encuentra en el otro array. Para esto se usa también el método **includes**. Este método determina si un array contiene o no determinado elemento devolviendo *true* en caso de contenerlo y *false* caso contrario. (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes)

Comment: Si amplias tu respuesta explicando la será de mejor calidad y le ayudarás más al OP

Comment: Okey gracias por revisarlo, ahí te parece mejor?